# @RequestParam with optional is throwing "param not present" error in java 8 Controller

Tags: java-8, controller

We have a spring controller with a param marked as optional like below

```
String myMethod(
        @RequestParam(value = "email") Optional<String> email,
        @RequestParam(value = "userName") Optional<Long> userId) {
```

This throws an error if our request does not have email, even though Java 8 mentions that a param marked as Optional is not required.

So why is the param still being checked?

Answer (score 0):

what is the version of your Spring Framework? because it was introduced in later versions of Spring.

In Spring MVC, starting from version 4.3, if you use Optional as a method parameter with @RequestParam and the parameter is missing in the request, Spring will automatically populate the Optional with Optional.empty().

Comment: We are on 5.2 version

Answer (score 0):

Found out it was a simple issue of older code being present in the environment being checked. Using Optional works as intended after refreshing the code.